# angularjs view render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Есть Контронтроллер для вьюхи, в случае нажатии на кнопку "Удалить"/"Добавить" с помощью кастомного сервиса в `localStorage` удаляется часть данных.

После в сервисе срабатывает событие, которое опять же отлавливается в Контроллере дабы изменить данные в `$scope` для отображения. Удаляется всё правильно, быстро и хорошо, но вот отображение перерисовывается странно...

При первом нажатии отображается новые данные + старые и спустя примерно пол секунды старые исчезают. Поставил в контроллере `$watch` на данные в `$scope`, которые выводятся, срабатывает как и должно - только один раз ...

Может кто сталкивался, подскажите, где смотреть?

Код контроллера:

```
App.controller('favoritesCtrl', [

    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'stat',
    'Favorites',

    function ($scope, $rootScope, stat, Favorites) {

        var FavoriteUsers = Favorites.getList();

        $scope.favoriteList = [];
        $scope.$on('changeUserList', function() {
            // _log('(favoritesCtrl) Fire changeUserList ...', arguments);
            $scope.favoriteList = stat.getByKeys(FavoriteUsers);
        });

        $scope.removeFromFavorites = function(id) {
            Favorites.Remove(id);
        };

        $scope.$watch('favoriteList', function() {
            _log('(favoritesCtrl) $watch favoriteList:', arguments);
        });

        // Изменение списка избранных
        $scope.$on('Favorites_Change', function(event, list) {
            _log('(favoritesCtrl) Favorites_Change:', arguments);
            $scope.favoriteList = stat.getByKeys(list);
        });

        $scope.showDrop = function() {

        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Нужен рабочий воспроизводимый пример

Comment: 1- favoriteList это массив, для него не походит $watch. $watch только для примитивных данных (int, string) используйте $watchCollection для массивов и объектов     2- массивы и объекты передаются как референс, т.е. не стоит усложнять себе жизнь и делать локальную копию, всёравно получится ссылка на объект

Comment: @Grundy, приложение уже не маленькое, всё вывалить нельзя. Попробую сделать мини вариант и воспроизвести. Но что я уже заметил, возможно это и есть причина беды, шаблон 3 раза перерисовывается. Почему не понятно, ведь кроме как favoriteList там ничего не выводится, а судя по $watchCollection оно меняется 1 раз.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, в примере и не должно быть _всей_ программы, только минимальный код который нужен чтобы воспроизвести проблему

Comment: @Grundy, сделал проектик имитирующий, но как его там запустить не знаю http://plnkr.co/edit/ohwKZMKieoZf2HGAt3en. В принципе разобрался в чем может быть проблема, скорее всего в множественном перерендеринге, в указаном случае его 2, у меня в приложении больше. Скорее всего косяк в архитектуре ... Думал проблема в ng-include, попробовал через ui-view - то же самое ...

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, на планкре отличная коллекция подключаемый библиотек, особенно по ангуляру :) лучше их подключать а не через файл

Comment: @Grundy, a свои файлы как подключить?

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, какие свои? совсем свои? или свои которые библиотек?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36219/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-lemesh).